# Subscribe to the same Observable in a Child Component Angular2 / TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

this is a very simple question but I am new to Angular2 and although I can find good examples and tutorials sometimes I need a little more explaining.

So I have a compoent that has and observable, every so often the value of this updated. I have really edited my code here but here is the meat of my issue, you will notice an Observable called `product`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-profile',
  templateUrl: './product-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-profile.component.scss']
})
export class ProductProfileComponent {
// I have ommitted so much code here....
product: Observable<Product>;

constructor(
        private store: Store<any>
    ) {

        this.product = this.store
                    .let(getProductStore)
                    .let(getProductProfile);

        this.product
            .select((product: Product) => product && product.id)
            .subscribe(productId => this.productId = productId
            });
        }

// I have omitted so much code here....
}
```

Now I have a Child component that may not be a direct child but perhaps nested deep down in a third or forth level component, something like so

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-footer',
  templateUrl: './product-footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-footer.component.scss']
})
export class ProductFooterComponent {

// this is the same Observable / property from the parent
// when there is a change in the parent I want to update the property below... 
product: Observable<Product>;

constructor(){}
}
```

Now here's where I don't know what to do. How would I update the product property in the Child component when there is a change in value to the product property in the parent. Should I use `@Input()`? I thought about this but as the relationship is not a direct Parent> Child relationship I am unsure how this would work? Should I use some sort of `EventEmitter`? Any advice / links would be appreciated, I'm currently a bit lost and my resources don't seem applicable!

Answer (score 0):

You COULD pass it all the way down through your components, but I like to do something a bit different when there's a lot of nesting like you're saying. I create a new service that I scope to the top level component, and the child component just injects that and accesses fields there.

For example, I've got a "Workspace" service, that handles communicating actions between child components and the top level "Workspace" component. And the best part is since it's scoped to this top level component, you don't have to worry about the rest of your app muddying with this service.

Workspace service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class WorkspaceService {

    public observable: Observable<any>;

}
```

Top level component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    providers: [ WorkspaceService ]
})
export class TopLevelWorkspaceComponent {

    constructor(private workspaceService: WorkspaceService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.workspaceService.observable = /*create observable*/;
    }

}
```

Child:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id
})
export class NestedComponentUnderWorkspace {

    constructor(private workspaceService: WorkspaceService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.workspaceService.observable.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }

}
```

Comment: What would go in /*create observable*/;? Just set it equal to a variable? If I follow your pattern I get "'subscribe' of undefined" from the child component.